# gnuplot warning: "plotting with an unknown terminal"

Tags: terminal, macos, homebrew, xquartz

I'm trying to use gnuplot on my MacBook Air (Mac OS X 10.11.3).
I have installed XQuartz by using homebrew after I installed gnuplot (with this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AR-GUSkqMCU).
But gnuplot did not work and terminal showed: Terminal type is now 'unknown'.

For example, I wanted to plot sin(x) and I got a error message as the following:

```
gnuplot> plot(sin(x))
WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install DirectX11 and XQuartz.
Restart your Mac and Retry.

https://csml-wiki.northwestern.edu/index.php/Binary_versions_of_Gnuplot_for_OS_X:

> Binary versions of Gnuplot for OS X/macOS. These are primarily
>   intended for users who normally work on Linux and wish to replicate
>   their tools on a Macintosh.
>
> - Compiled on OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan). Confirmed to work also on macOS 10.13 (High Sierra).
> - Prior to installing this, you need to install X11/XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).
> - The versions provided here include the GNU Readline library.
> - In addition to the standard terminals, the PDF terminal is included as well.
> - Simply download the package from one of the links below and install. You can then invoke gnuplot from a terminal window via
>     /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
> - Currently available versions:
>
>   - [5.2.2](http://ariadne.ms.northwestern.edu/Download/Gnuplot/gnuplot-5.2.2.pkg)
>   - [5.2.3](http://ariadne.ms.northwestern.edu/Download/Gnuplot/gnuplot-5.2.3.pkg)